# use same value on 2 inputs on keyup if first one is originaly empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, input

I have 2 fields in a form Name and Company and I want Name to dynamically get the Company value while it's typed (only if Name is empty when you start imputing Company) and i'm not finding out the best way to achieve this.

for example purposes the HTML is:

```
<form>
    ...
    <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" value="">
    <input type="text" id="Company" name="Name" value="">
    ...
</form>
```

i tried:

```
$('#Company').on('keyup', function(){
    var str = $('#Company').val();
    str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);

    if($('#Name').val().length <= 0 || $('#Name').val() == str){
        $('#Name').val($('#Company').val());
    }
});
```

and it works to some extent, if you type in too quickly it stops assuming `#Name` and `#Company` had the same value before last `keyup`

I also thought about doing on Company `blur` and it'll probably work, but that is not the user experience i was wanting to achieve.

This would probably be easier using Angular.js or the likes of that, but using that now is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, adding a class that is removed on input into the name field, otherwise the length check will fail after the first character is copied from the Company field.

```js
$('#Name').addClass('empty').on('input', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('empty', this.value.trim().length === 0);
});

$('#Company').on('input', function() {
    $('#Name.empty').val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    Name : <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" value=""><br>
    Comp : <input type="text" id="Company" name="Name" value="">
</form>
```